# Ionic 3 using JavaScript library xterm.js

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, xtermjs

I'm trying to use the xterm.js library for an Ionic 3 project.

Github has the source: https://github.com/aircable/ionic-xterm and instructions. It compiles and starts, but it does not show correctly, or at all. Layout is wrong.

Other problems are the loading of addons. Several of these attempts are commented out.

Here is an excerpt from home.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as Terminal from "xterm";
//import style from 'xterm/dist/xterm.css';
import "xterm/dist/addons/fit/fit";

@Component({
  selector: 'terminal',
  templateUrl: "home.html",
  //styles: [ style ]
  //styleUrls: ["./xterm.css"]
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  private term: Terminal;

  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController ) {

    this.term = new Terminal( {cursorBlink: true} );
    this.term.open( document.getElementById("terminal") );

    //Terminal.loadAddon( "fit" );

    //this.term.fit();

    this.term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');

    // this is
    this.term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
      console.log( key );
    });

  }

  ngOnInit () {}

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the use case of this library on your ionic project? Any console errors?

Comment: This is xterm: https://github.com/sourcelair/xterm.js
A library to create terminals in web pages. You could connect that to ssh or anything.
See quickstart: https://xtermjs.org/
Similar to this online demo: http://vtortola.github.io/ng-terminal-emulator/1

My goal is to create a portable app for web, ios and android that connects the terminal to a Bluetooth-to-serial device. Depending on where it runs, it uses either Web Bluetooth or Ionic native BLE from Cordova.

Comment: There are no errors on the console, there is no compile error.

Comment: Your `online demo` url is not working? Question: If you used `Native BLE plugin` then hope you cannot use that on the web no? Are you developing PWA app?

Comment: Make some changes on the project, now it sort of works, but many thing are unexplained. Ideas what's going on with the fit to <ion-textbox>?

Comment: @JuergenKienhoefer can you provide a screenshot of your screen with xterm.js loaded, along with the logs of your browser's console?

This will help debug the whole thing :).

Answer (score 2):

Got most of it working, only the fit addon does not. But no errors.
I adjust the row attribute to select the size.
Look at the source on Github: https://github.com/aircable/ionic-xterm

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as Terminal from "xterm";
//import style from 'xterm/dist/xterm.css';
import "xterm/dist/addons/fit/fit";

@Component({
    selector: 'terminal',
    templateUrl: "home.html",
    //styles: [ style ]
    //styleUrls: ["./xterm.css"]
})

export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {

    private term: Terminal;
    // this finds the #terminal element, after view init
    @ViewChild('terminal' ) terminal: ElementRef;

    constructor(public navCtrl:NavController) {

        Terminal.loadAddon("fit");

        this.term = new Terminal({
            cursorBlink: true,
            //useStyle: true,
            scrollback: 60,
            rows: 30,
        });

        // this is just simple echo
        this.term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
            console.log(key.charCodeAt(0));
            if (key.charCodeAt(0) == 13)
                this.term.write('\n');
            this.term.write(key);
        });

    }

    // getting the nativeElement only possible after view init
    ngAfterViewInit() {

        // this now finds the #terminal element
        this.term.open( this.terminal.nativeElement, true );

        // calling fit is not quite working
        // uses the obscure ion-textbox, which does not really exist, but changes the font size
        // the number of rows will determine the size of the terminal screen
        this.term.fit();
        this.term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');

    }
```